# What behaviour would I see for an interpreter that uses applicaitve-order evaluation vs a normal-order based interpreter?

Tags: scheme, interpreter, sicp

This is the code:

```
(define (p) (p))
(define (test x y) 
     (if    (= x 0) 
          0 
          y))
(test 0 (p))
```

What I think(not sure) is that for applicative-order interpreter, (p) procedure is evaluated first
   which results in an infinite loop.

While
   for the normal-order interpreter, test procedure is evaluated, which results
   in test procedure returning 0. So p procedure will not be
   evaluated.

Comment: This has exactly the same code as [seek for some explanation on SICP exercise 1.5](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16036139/1281433)  which, in turn, is from the [SICP book](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-10.html#%_thm_1.5).  You really shouldn't copy and paste other people's code without attribution.

Comment: This question was given by my professor as an exercise. So, I didn't know it was from a book or on this amazing site. I'm sorry if my actions offended anyone

Comment: Understood.  Your professor also shouldn't copy material from textbooks without attribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumptions are right, evaluation occurs just as predicted. In an applicative-order evaluator the parameters to a function call are evaluated *before* binding them to the procedure's parameters - so the argument `(p)` will result in an infinite loop, and we'll never enter `test`'s body.

On the other hand, a normal-order interpreter delays evaluation until the last moment, and the `(p)` invocation will not be evaluated until needed - in other words, `(test 0 (p))` will not result in an infinite loop because this execution path never uses the `y` parameter (which was bound to `(p)`), whereas `(test 1 (p))` *will* loop forever because we manage to reach the point where `y` is being used to produce a value.

Testing this is easy for the applicative-order interpreter - that's how standard Scheme works. For testing the normal-order evaluation, you can use an special interpreter with lazy evaluation, like the one implemented in [chapter 4 of SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-27.html#%_sec_4.2).

Comment: It appears that OP is already working through the SICP book.